# sorting a web cookie env

Tags: perl, cookies

I am currently messing around with Perl and web cookies. I'm collecting information from the HTTP_COOKIE environment variable however I am stuck on how I can sort the results.

The simple "sort { $cookie }" is just fine for me, however when using the split function I'm stuck. Is there any way to sort the array?

Collecting the data:

```
sub netcookie {;
my $cookie = $ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'};
#foxcookie 
};

my $cookie = netcookie();
```

I have a dynamic loading website which loads a temple file based on the "level" value of the cookie.

When user passes authentication the cookie gets updated with the stamp, sprite and palace and so the cookie looks like this:

```
HTTP_COOKIE 
stamp=stamps/stamp.0.113646176072308; 
sprite=stamps/sprite.0.385163302390964; 
palace=stamps/palace.0.57031374346893;     
level=5.0:Palace; 
magic=palace.pixc
```

Prior to this, the cookie looks like this which can be easily mapped to $level and $magic

```
HTTP_COOKIE 
level=2.3:FoxCookie; 
magic=foxcookie.pixc;
```

the code im using is:

```
my ($level,$magic,$stamp,$sprite,$palace) = split ';', $cookie; 
#split $cookie in to variables delimited by ;
```

However due to additional cookie values I add later, $level no longer becomes $level and ends up just becoming all mixed.

If sort(blah) isn't really viable what would be the next best way?

```
if ($level =~ 'level=5.0:Palace') 
#If the cookie contains level palace
{
print "Welcome to the TeddyPortal of the CrystalForest Palace";
rawr::fountain::magic("$level","$magic");
}
```

I've tried such:

```
my $cube = sort($cookie);
my @cube = sort($cookie);
my &cube = sort($cookie);
```

All come with failed results. However neither can I seem to use:

```
my $cookie = sort(netcookie());
```

tl;dr: sort on a split

Thanks,
Mookie

Comment: `sort` operates on a list. Your `$cookie` var is a string, so there's nothing to sort. If you wanted to sort the data by the key names you would do `my @sorted = sort(split ';', $cookie)`. However, this is a bit irrrelevant to what you want to do, which is to identify the parts of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `hash` to record the cookie key names as hash keys, by spltting the data twice: once on ';' and then again on '='

```
my @parts = split /;\s*/, $cookie;
my %hash;
for my $part (@parts) {
    my ($key,$val) = split /=/, $part;
    $hash{$key} = $val;
}
```

Here's a more concise version. You can do this because a hash can be expressed as a list of key-value pairs.

```
my %hash = map {split /=/, $_} split /;\s*/, $cookie;
```

Access the values like: `print $hash{level}."\n"`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm aiming for. However, I am still failing to collect the values of other keys. print $hash{palace} prints nothing while $hash{level} works fine however, I can confirm everything is correct via dumper. Can i only print out the last value?

Comment: Edited to account for whitespace / newlines in the string